# ibm_db multiline sql query execution issue

Tags: python-3.x, db2

I am trying to run a multi line query on a DB2 Database using ibm_db via python script. But when the script is executed it is executing as boolean exp instead of a sql statement which is why am not able to get the result. Can anyone help me.

```
import ibm_db
sql = """ Multi line sql statement with multiple joins across tables """

stmt = ibm_db.execute_immediate(conn,sql)

dictionary = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)

print(type(dictionary))

print(dictionary)
```

Result:

```
type boolean

False
```

Whereas when I try to execute a single line statement it is running perfectly fine. I am need help badly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

not execute_immediate, but ibm_db.exec_immediate https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs#ibm_dbexec_immediate

Show me an example of your multiline query.

In the test code there is a long query and they work. False means that you have an error in the request itself.

[image]